# C# How to retrieve code from a process and then run it?

Tags: c#, windows, process, arrays, exe

Since a process is an instance of a computer program and contains the program code and its current activity, I tried the following thing :

- Parse my process and retrieve an array of bytes.
- Execute those bytes.

My problem is that I retrieve both program code and its current activity, while I'm interested in just the first part.

Here is how I retrieve the bytes of my process "foo" :

```
 public static byte[] retrieveProcessBytes(String processName) {
        Process process = ApplicationFinder.FromProcessName(processName).First();
        var sharp = new MemorySharp(process);

        List<byte> bytes = new List<byte>();
        IntPtr ptr = IntPtr.Zero;
        try
        {
            while (true) {
                bytes.Add(sharp.Read<byte>(ptr, 1)[0]);
                ptr = IntPtr.Add(ptr, 1);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            Console.Write("Exception caught : " + e);
        }
        return bytes.ToArray();
    }
```

And here is how I try to execute it :

```
byte[] bytes = retrieveProcessBytes("foo");
Assembly asm = Assembly.Load(bytes);
Object[] Args = new Object[0];
asm.EntryPoint.Invoke(null, Args);
```

And it gives me the following error :

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.BadImageFormatException' occurred in mscorlib.dll

Meanwhile if I retrieve the bytes from my "foo.exe" program and execute them, as below, it works.

```
Byte[] bytes = File.ReadAllBytes(pathToFooExe);
Assembly asm = Assembly.Load(bytes);
```

The byte array that I retrieve from my process is significantly larger than the one I retrieve from my "foo.exe" file. Because I suppose that I retrieve the current process activity too.

How can I retrieve just the code part of my process ?

Does it start to IntPtr.Zero or later ? And when do I stop ?

Any help would be appreciated, Thanks in advance.

Comment: This is a very simplified way of viewing it. But you can't just extract the program out of a running process like that. Firstly the memory isn't a linear block, secondly there are also other loaded modules (assemblies/DLLs, etc.) in the process' memory and thirdly the EXE file isn't loaded 1:1 into memory. For more details about the EXE file format and how it is loaded into memory, check [this](http://wiki.osdev.org/PE#Loading_a_PE_file) out.

Comment: What is your goal of this operation anyway? There is probably a better solution to achieve what you want.

Comment: I want to compare if the code in my process is the same as the one from the exe file. And if its usual for programs to differ at runtime, like programs with DRMs or protections.

Comment: In your own process or in another process? In any case, you could specifically check the code section and/or data section and compare them against the corresponding sections in the EXE file (see again the link I posted above for the file format). But be aware that there might be third-party software such as antiviruses patching your code at runtime as well (e.g. COMODO does/did that, and I ran into issues because of this in the past).

Answer (score 0):

If you read about the function Assembly.Load you can see that you are using it improperly. Just because it allows an array of bytes as input doesn't mean you are feeding it a proper array of bytes.

[Assembly.Load(Byte[])](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.assembly.load(v=vs.110).aspx)

> Loads the assembly with a common object file format (COFF)-based image containing an emitted assembly. The assembly is loaded into the application domain of the caller.

[COFF file format](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/COFF)

This isn't what you are doing obviously. Basically, what you are doing cannot be done. CherryDT has given you good reason above in his comments as well.